# Python Pandas: Write a function to quickly calculate MAPE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have prepared a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
| Date       | Actual | Predicted |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-01-01 | XX     | XX        |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-01-02 | XX     | XX        |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-01-03 | XX     | XX        |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-01-04 | XX     | XX        |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-01-05 | XX     | XX        |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2020-01-06 | XX     | XX        |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| ...        | ...    | ...       |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

**MAPE = [Σ(|Actual - Predicted| / Actual)] / *100 / N** 

(formula is also available here: https://ibf.org/knowledge/glossary/mape-mean-absolute-percentage-error-174)

N would be the number of rows.

Right now I am doing a very manual labor, by adding in an extra column that calculates |Actual - Predicted|, another column that calculates (|Actual - Predicted| / Actual), and then sum up that column, multiply by 100, and then divided by number of rows.

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way for me to do this by **writing a function that helps me automate this MAPE calculating process**.

I imagine the input to be the dataframe, the two column names "actual" and "predicted", and the output would be calculated MAPE.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed how you would do it. However, you can chain your operations:

```
df['MAPE'] = ((df.Actual-df.Predicted).abs()
                 .div(df.Actual)
                 .cumsum()
                 /np.arange(1,len(df)+1)
             )
```

Test data and output:

```
   Actual  Predicted      MAPE
0      10          5  0.500000
1      11          6  0.477273
2      12          7  0.457071
3      13          8  0.438957
4      14          9  0.422594
```

Comment: Always the fastest and the best solution :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't MAPE a single number? This solutions seems to show it as a vector that is of equal length as the actual and the predicted values. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is annoying, as @Iterator516 pointed out, MAPE is a single value.

The following performs this calculation

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(10, 15)
y = np.random.randint(10, 15, size=x.size)

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(y)], axis=1)
df.columns = ['predicted', 'actual']

mape = ((df.actual-df.predicted).abs() / df.actual).mean()

print(mape)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this and doesn't want to create their own function, you can use the one provided by scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error as mape

mape_value = mape(df.Actual, df.Predicted)
```

Using the function like this will return a single float value, but you can tweak the parameters to return an ndarray if needed.

Documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html